# PostgreSQL in R: Find row in db with variable existing in R vector

Tags: r, postgresql

I am new to sql and databases in general, so bear with me.

I have an R vector:

```
my.vector <- c(2,4,6,8,10)
```

I then need to find the rows in a postgreSQL database, where the value in a specific column matches any of the values in my.vector.

I can do this:

```
my.db <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "
     SELECT *
     FROM database
     WHERE my.colum = my.vector")
```

This does of cause not work, but how do I do it?

Comment: Try "SELECT * FROM database WHERE my.colum in (2,4,6,8,10);". I am not sure if substitution my.vector works, you can check that

Comment: My real vector has more than 100,000 numbers in it :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate your query dynamically. You can do that with `sprintf`/`paste0`. Try :

```
my.vector <- c(2,4,6,8,10)
query <- sprintf('SELECT * FROM database WHERE my.colum in (%s)', toString(my.vector))
query
#[1] "SELECT * FROM database WHERE my.colum in (2, 4, 6, 8, 10)"

my.db <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con, query)
```

Comment: When I try I get the following error: Error in postgresqlExecStatement (conn, statement, ...): RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR : operator does not exist: text = bigint.       LINE1: ... WHERE my.column in (arrow pointing at the i)

Comment: Is `my.column` of string/character type? In which case you can try `query <- sprintf('SELECT * FROM database WHERE my.colum in ("%s")', paste0(my.vector, collapse = '","'))`

Comment: The word "dynamic" helped my google a bit. It now works if I write query<-paste0('SELECT * FROM database WHERE my.column =", my.vector) if I make the vector like in my example. However if I make a column from another table into my.vector it doesn't work - any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: What code do you use to make column from another table into `my.vector`? Can you try `query<-paste0('SELECT * FROM database WHERE my.column =', df$column)`